# geth private network is which type of node?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, proof-of-correctness, web3py

I'm new to blockchain, I have setup on private node using geth.

Now I want to know, which kind of chain it is called **PoA based chain or PoW**?

below is my command to start private node:

geth --nodiscover --networkid 1111 --datadir node1 --unlock ADD --rpccorsdomain="*" --mine --rpc --rpcapi "admin,debug,eth,miner,net,personal,txpool,web3,clique" --nousb --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --ws.api "eth,net,web3,debug,txpool" --ws --ws.addr 0.0.0.0 --ws.port 8546 --ws.origins "*" --syncmode=full --gcmode=archive --rpcvhosts=* --allow-insecure-unlock console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your `genesis.json` config, not on the CLI params.

You're using Proof of Authority (PoA) if you have the `clique` defined in the config. If you don't have it, you're using Proof of Work (PoW).

For more info, see "Clique Example" in the [docs](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/private-network).

Comment: Thank You soo much @Petr, 

Now just more curious to know which one will be better to use ?

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution It depends on your use case... First of all, it's discouraged here at StackOverflow to ask/answer opinion-based questions and answers, because it tends to bring heated arguments and flamewars sometimes... Apart from that, PoA can be better for one thing, PoW can be better for other. So it really does depend and I'm not able to answer without more context.... But my personal opinion in this situation is that unless you need a specific consensus algorithm, I'd go with the default one (which is PoW) simply because there might be more documentation and support available.